# elFinder errUnknownCmd FTP integration

Tags: php, ftp, connection, integration, elfinder

i'm trying to integrate a ftp client into my web portal using elFinder but when i try to connect i get this error: {"error":["errUnknownCmd"]}.
I enabled debug from $opts array but i got nothing else.

this is my connector:

> ```
> include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinder.class_.php';
>
> function access($attr, $path, $data, $volume) {
> return strpos(basename($path), '.') === 0 // if file/folder begins with '.' (dot)
> ? !($attr == 'read' || $attr == 'write') // set read+write to false, other (locked+hidden) set to true
> : null; // else elFinder decide it itself
> }
>
> //$usr=$db->queryToRow("Select nome, password from BTK_INTRANET..ftp_utenti where id = ".$LOGIN["id"]);
>
> $opts = array(
> 'debug' => true,
> 'roots' => array(
> array(
> 'driver' => 'FTP',
> 'host' => 'localhost',
> 'user' => 'admin',
> 'pass' => 'admin',
> 'path' => '/',
> 'tmpPath' => '../files/ftp'
> )
> )
> );
>
> // run elFinder
> $connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts),true);
> $connector->run();
> ```

NOTE: i did a unique php file with all necessary classes (elFinderConnector.class.php, elFinder.class.php, elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php, elFinderVolumeFTP.class.php). With separated classes i have same situation.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the FTP module, if you are connecting with FTP.
Add the following at the very beginning, after your other include

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinderVolumeFTP.class.php';
```